# unordered_map hash function c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map, hash-function

I need to define an unordered_map like this `unordered_map<pair<int, int>, *Foo>`, what is the syntax for defining and passing a `hash` and `equal` functions to this map?

I've tried passing to it this object:

```
class pairHash{
public:
    long operator()(const pair<int, int> &k) const{
        return k.first * 100 + k.second;
    }
};
```

and no luck:

```
unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int> map = unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int>(1,
*(new pairHash()));
```

I have no Idea what is the `size_type_Buskets` means so I gave it `1`.
What is the right way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: `*(new pairHash())` Who is going to delete this? Why are you doing dynamic allocation here? Just use `pairHash()`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is an unfortunate omission in C++11; Boost has the answer in terms of `hash_combine`. Feel free to just paste it from them! Here's how I hash pairs:

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t & seed, const T & v)
{
  std::hash<T> hasher;
  seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

namespace std
{
  template<typename S, typename T> struct hash<pair<S, T>>
  {
    inline size_t operator()(const pair<S, T> & v) const
    {
      size_t seed = 0;
      ::hash_combine(seed, v.first);
      ::hash_combine(seed, v.second);
      return seed;
    }
  };
}
```

You can use `hash_combine` as the basis for many other things, like tuples and ranges, so you could hash an entire (ordered) container, for example, as long as each member is individually hashable.

Now you can just declare a new map:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, my_mapped_type> mymap;
```

---

If you want to use your homebrew hasher (which hasn't got good statistical properties), you have to specify the template parameters explicitly:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>, int, pairHash> yourmap;
```

Note that there's no need to specify a copy of a hasher object, as the default is to default-construct one for you.

Comment: @Vlad: Hmm... well, with the pair hash specialization, you can just write `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int> map;` and not worry any further... If you really want a named hasher, you have to specify all four template parameters, `<Key, Value, EqualPred, Hasher>`.

Comment: Whoa, easy on the hostility :-) Check my previous comment: if you want to specify your own hasher class, you have to explicitly name all four template parameters, which you aren't doing. I added a line on how to do that.

Comment: @Kerrek SB You got the order of the 4 template parameters wrong, the equal predicate follows the hasher. Also, I like this method better than what I have posted, but maybe Vlad has to use this custom hash function.

Comment: @Praetorian: Ohh, thank you, how silly -- in that case it's much easier, because you don't need to list the fourth parameter at all.

Comment: @Kerrek SB No, it seems you don't. I didn't know there was an `operator==` defined for `std::pair`.

Comment: @Praetorian: Yeah, `pair` is a cool class. It basically does everything you expect straight out of the box. I really don't know why the hasher wasn't also included in the new version... :-(

Comment: When I try adding the code, I get a syntax error missing ';' before '<' on the line 'template<typename S, typename T> struct hash<pair<S, T>>'

Am I missing something?

Comment: @bpeikes: Try leaving a space between the angled brackets.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek, turned out that the error was because the version of VS I was compiling with had issues with "hash" I had to change it to std::tr1::hash.

Comment: Isn't specializing in `std` for a type also in `std` illegal?  It really *should* be...

Comment: @Yakk: No. You're explicitly allowed and encouraged to add specializations to `std` (but not *overloads*!), as long as you adhere to various contracts laid out by the standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB Add specializations to `std` for your own types: but for types in `std`?  That just seems like you are aching to interfere with the next version of the library.  Aha, here it is: "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std _only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type_ and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited." -- your specialization does not depend on a user-defined type, so is prohibited.  Punchline?  That was from one of your own answers!

Answer (score 10):

The return type of the hash function should be `size_t`, not `long` (although this is not the cause of the error). The syntax you've shown for providing a custom hash function is incorrect.

You'll also need to provide an equal predicate to make the above work properly.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class pairHash{
public:
    size_t operator()(const pair<int, int> &k) const{
        return k.first * 100 + k.second;
    }
};

struct pairEquals : binary_function<const pair<int,int>&, const pair<int,int>&, bool> {
  result_type operator()( first_argument_type lhs, second_argument_type rhs ) const
  {
    return (lhs.first == rhs.first) && (lhs.second == rhs.second);
  }
};     

int main()
{
  unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int, pairHash, pairEquals> myMap;

  myMap[make_pair(10,20)] = 100;
  myMap.insert( make_pair(make_pair(100,200), 1000) );
}
```

**EDIT:**
You don't need to define the equal predicate since `operator==` is defined for `std::pair` and it does exactly what I've done in `pairEquals`. You'll only need the `pairEquals` definition if you expect the comparison to be done differently.

Comment: Equality for pairs is already defined by default, as is lexicographic ordering... it's really quite a handy little class :-)

Comment: binary_function seems to be deprecated as of C++ 11 - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/binary_function/

Answer (score 10):

If you are fine with using Boost, a cleaner solution is to rely on Boost's implementation of the hash function for pairs (which in fact does exactly what kerrek-sb explains in his answer). Therefore all you have to do is:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int, hash<pair<int, int>>> table;
```

Comment: A good solution, but I wouldn't use the namespace. I would write it out. It's pretty important here what comes from which namespace.

Comment: I also very appreciate this answer and I am not really sure whether the top answer should be considered a good practice. Defining such home-brew helper functions only pollutes code imho.