# How to use an unordered_map of fixed array and int?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, unordered-map

My code works just fine when I use `map< array<int,FIXEDSIZE>, int>` but not when I use `unordered_map< array<int,FIXEDSIZE>, int>`.

It creates this massive list of errors so I don't really know what's wrong. Things like "value" is not a member, or "no match for operator[]", etc.

This is how I am using my map (which I name `cache`):

```
if (cache.find(key) != cache.end()) return cache[key];
```

and

```
cache[key] = valueToMemoize;
```

Comment: Why would you want something like this?

Comment: @101010 Memoization speed. In my experience, whenever unordered_map works, it's always a heck of a lot faster than using a regular map. I am trying to get unordered_map to work so I can compare.

Comment: You need to write a hasher. `std::array` comes with comparison operators (making it usable in `map`s), but no hashers.

Comment: @T.C. How would I do that for this particular case? I am not familiar with writing hashers or how I'd get it to speak to this datatype / whenever I use it like I've described.

Comment: As a side note, `if (cache.find(key) != cache.end()) return cache[key];` searches for `key` twice. You should use `at` for that, or access the value by the iterator.

Comment: Unless there is a better way to memoize a small array of integers (with values < 128 each)?

Comment: @LogicStuff Sorry, I am not familiar. What do you mean using `at`? How is it searching for the key twice when I only use `find()` once?

Comment: @LogicStuff I assumed it was constant-time lookup when you already know the index. To my knowledge `operator[]` is not a search unless I am really mistaken about how maps work

Comment: @user5613205 `[]` searches for it again, but `at()` doesn't help either.

Comment: "memoize a small array of integers (with values < 128 each)". `std::string` should work in a pinch.

Comment: @T.C. I mean `at` replacing it all, with catching the exception to determine failure.

Comment: Is there no better way to do a "return value if corresponding key is in cache"?

Comment: @LogicStuff Using exceptions for flow control? /shudder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically what `boost::hash_combine` boils down to:

```
void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, std::size_t value) {
    seed ^= value + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}
```

A simple hasher for containers - hash all of their elements using `std::hash`, and combine them.

```
struct container_hasher {
     template<class T>
     std::size_t operator()(const T& c) const {
         std::size_t seed = 0;
         for(const auto& elem : c) {
             hash_combine(seed, std::hash<typename T::value_type>()(elem));
         }
         return seed;
     }
};
```

Use:

```
std::unordered_map<std::array<int, 10>, int, container_hasher> my_map;
```

---

For cheaper lookup, do

```
auto r = cache.find(key);
if(r != cache.end()) return r->second;
```

For `std::map`, you might want to use `lower_bound` instead, to help with the later insertion:

```
auto lb = cache.lower_bound(key);
if(lb != cache.end() && lb->first == key) return lb->second;
cache.emplace_hint(lb, key, valueToMemoize);
```

Comment: I had found something similar at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222143/unordered-map-hash-function-c so I am at least happy to know I was on the right track. Thank you for this! I'll have to study this a little to better understand how it works.

Comment: Also what is `value + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);`?

Comment: @user5613205: Note that combining hashes produces low-quality hashing which may perform poorly on certain inputs (and is attackable). While hash combining can be used to make the code "work", there's no substitute for hashing all the ingredient bits of the data in one go -- which is not easy to do with the current library design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your custom hash object like below:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class arrayHash {
public:
  std::size_t operator()(std::array<T, N> const &arr) const {
    std::size_t sum(0);
    for(auto &&i : arr) sum += std::hash<T>()(i);
    return sum;
  }
};
```

And then define your `unordered_map` as:

```
std::unordered_map<std::array<int, FIXEDSIZE>, int, arrayHash<int, FIXEDSIZE>> umap;
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/840404b0a8b69608)