# Invoke std::hash() through constructor in unordered_map wrapper in C++

Tags: c++, template-specialization, unordered-map

We are trying to set `mHashCode` either through template specialization of `operator()`(string in this case) or through the c'tor of `HashFunction()` by the user provided key(here, `inKey`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

template< class Key > class HashFunction
{
  public:
    HashFunction( const Key & k );

    inline operator unsigned() const
    {
      return mHashCode;
    }
    size_t operator()(const Key &k) const;

  private:
    unsigned mHashCode;
};

template<> HashFunction< string >::HashFunction( const string & k )
{
  mHashCode=std::hash<string>{}(k);
}

template <> size_t HashFunction< string >::operator()(const string &k) const 
{
  return mHashCode;
}

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash = HashFunction< Key > >
class unordered_map_wrapper
{
  public:
   unordered_map_wrapper();
  private:
    unordered_map<Key, Val, Hash> * mTable;
};

template< class Key, class Val, class Hash >
unordered_map_wrapper< Key, Val, Hash >::unordered_map_wrapper()
{
    mTable=new unordered_map<Key, Val, Hash>(5);
}

int main() {
    unordered_map_wrapper<string, unsigned> h;
    return 0;
}
```

If the user is passing the hash function(not match with `string`, `unsigned` etc.) along with the `hash()` constructor, this `mHashCode` is generated by hitting the c'tor of `HashFunction()`. An object of `HashFunction` class will be created in this case. Due to this reason, `mHashCode` will generate and default template specialization of `operator()` will get control and return `mHashCode`. i.e. it's returning user's value only.

Template specialization is using `operator unsigned()`(specilization of constructor), creating an object and returning `mHashCode`.

Its working fine if we are passing hash function with the help of template argument and by default, it's using operator(), not the c'tor of `HashFunction()`. Getting a compile time error if we are using c'tor like the above snippet.

How could we set `mHashCode` through this c'tor so that user can use `std::Hash()`? Our hard requirement is that we need to invoke `std::hash()` through c'tor, not through the operator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... What even is the goal here?

Comment: A problem you are going to run into is that `HashFunction<Key>` is not default-constructible, which is required for it to be a stand-in for `std::hash<Key>`. There needs to be a `HashFunction()` constructor in order for you to use this type in this way.

Comment: A hash function needs to be able to hash more than one string. If you fix the hash code at construction it can't.

Comment: Can we use [something like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222143/unordered-map-hash-function-c):

`unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int> map = unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int>(1, *(new pairHash()));`

1 represents `size_type_Buskets`.